# Angular 2 tag validation not stopping submit

Tags: angular

Given the following code:

```
<form #theForm="ngForm" novalidate>
<div *ngIf="pickUpAddress.cannotVerify">
   <div class="form-group">
      <sh-manual-address [(ngModel)]="pickUpAddress" #manualAddress="ngModel" [address]="pickUpAddress" name="manualAddress"></sh-manual-address>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
<div>
    <button type="button" [disabled]="!theForm.control?.valid " (click)="navigateToConfirmation()">Continue</button>
</div>
```

And the custom part:

```
<ng-form name="manualAddress">
<div>
<div class="label">
      Postcode
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input ngControl="pickUpAddress.postcode" #postalcode="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="address.postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode"
        required/>
      <div *ngIf="postalcode.errors" class="input-error">Postcode is mandatory</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-form>
```

The issue is the Continue button becoming enabled even if the postcode is not filled out. In my understanding it should work, but not. Of course there are other elements in the form - those are preventing the button. What am I missing?

In other worlds: how can I make the two component talk to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what's going on, this was a great help:

```
<div [formGroup]="adressForm">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>street</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street">
        <small [hidden]="adressForm.controls.street.valid" class="text-danger">
            Street is required
        </small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>postcode</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postcode">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/clTbNP7MHBbBbrUp20vr?p=preview

Points to notice: Reactive, FormGroup, Validtor and FromBuilder.